# How to send message in Skype 6 with mouse click

Tags: skype

I know I can send messages with the keyboard pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key but is it possible to use the mouse? I can only see a smiley sign and no *Send message* or any other area, see the picture. Can you tell me how can use the mouse for sending?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Skype 7 on my system and had same problem . but if you can widen your Skype window from sides you can see the SEND button. then click on SEND button to send your messages with mouse click.

Comment: You were right, my window was not **wide enough**... :)